# Handling onTouch event in a custom container, with TextView as content

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, touch-event

I have the following problem.

In an Android application, there is a custom layout class, which extends the FrameLayout. It overrides the onTouchEvent method for a custom implementation. We have a TextView which resides as the content of this layout class. We want that the URL links in this TextView to be clickable. For that purpose, we add 'android:autoLink="web"' to the TextView's property. The following Xml ensues:

```
            <PinchZoomScrollView
                  android:layout_weight="350"
                  android:layout_width="0dp"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:id="@+id/newsDetailScrollView">

                <TextView 
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:autoLink="web"
                    android:id="@+id/newsDetailText"/>

            </PinchZoomScrollView>
```

After adding autoLink="web", it seems that the onTouchEvent of the custom layout class "PinchZoomEvent" is not being called. It seems that the TextView with the autoLink property blocks touch events somehow. This is weird since the PinchZoomScrollView is TextView's parent and it should receive the event first. What should be done in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parents don't automatically receive touches first in Android.  You're thinking of other frameworks.  Touch events start at the children and go up the chain in Android.  If you have a parent class such as a scroller that wants to intercept touch events and possible override the child behavior, it needs to implement onInterceptTouchEvent, and return true from it when it detects an action it wants to take from the children.